# iOS, face detection, detecting a location away from the face

Tags: ios, face-detection, core-image

I am trying to add face detection to my app, and the code I added gives me back a CGRect that has nothing to do with the face.

Here's the code

```
CIImage  *cIImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:self.imageView.image.CGImage];
CIDetector* faceDetector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace
                                          context:nil options:[NSDictionary  
       dictionaryWithObject:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh forKey:CIDetectorAccuracy]];
NSArray *features = [faceDetector featuresInImage:cIImage];
for(CIFaceFeature* faceObject in features)
{
    FaceLocation.x = faceObject.bounds.origin.x;
    FaceLocation.y = faceObject.bounds.origin.y;
}// Here face location is far off away form the actual face
```

But this code gives me a location far away from the actual face, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What about the size of the bounds? Why don't you look at the full bounds? Of course the origin is going to be off in the corner. That is why it's called origin and not center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the difference between the orientation in UIImage and CIDetectorImageOrientation. From iOS docs:

> CIDetectorImageOrientation
>
> A key used to specify the display orientation of the image whose features you want to detect. This key
> is an NSNumber object with the same value as defined by the TIFF and
> EXIF specifications; values can range from 1 through 8. The value
> specifies where the origin (0,0) of the image is located. If not
> present, the default value is 1, which means the origin of the image
> is top, left. For details on the image origin specified by each value,
> see kCGImagePropertyOrientation.
>
> Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
>
> Declared in CIDetector.h.

You have to specify the CIDetectorImageOrientation. Here is what I did:

```
int exifOrientation;
switch (self.image.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationUp:
        exifOrientation = 1;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationDown:
        exifOrientation = 3;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        exifOrientation = 8;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationRight:
        exifOrientation = 6;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        exifOrientation = 2;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
        exifOrientation = 4;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        exifOrientation = 5;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        exifOrientation = 7;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

NSDictionary *detectorOptions = @{ CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyHigh };
CIDetector *faceDetector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:nil options:detectorOptions];

NSArray *features = [faceDetector featuresInImage:[CIImage imageWithCGImage:self.image.CGImage]
                                          options:@{CIDetectorImageOrientation:[NSNumber numberWithInt:exifOrientation]}];
```

After the feature is detected, you also need to map the coordinate into the uiimage view, use my gist here: https://gist.github.com/laoyang/5747004 to convert the coordinate system

Comment: hi, I don;t know how to implelemt this gist!! should O just copy and paste everything in it? I am new to xcode.

Comment: It's already implemented. Just copy the file, and use it. It's a category on CIFaceFeature

Answer (score 0):

**iOS 10 and Swift 3**

**If you not interest in face features**

You can check apple [example](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCamBarcode/Introduction/Intro.html) you can detect face it's work very well with **Orientation**

you can select the face metedata to make camera track the face and show yellow box on the face

its have good **performance** than this [example](https://github.com/wayn/SquareCam-Swift)